# Formatting measure with text in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to create measure with text and numeric value, for instance:
"The number of customers in China: " & [measure] 7,900

[measure] is formatted to have separated thousands, but in concatenation values are without separation. Do you know how can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Use DAX function FORMAT

Comment: Show what [measure] contains and where from 7,900 coming from. And finally what is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formatting is set on the measure, but as soon as the measure is used within a new measure, it is this new measure that decides the formatting of the entire output.

You need to invoke `FORMAT` around your measure and specify you want thousand separators in the output, and concatenate this with your string:

```
# Cust in China :=
"The number of customers in China: " &
FORMAT ( [measure] , "#,###" )
```